# Wordpress - Display in Widget Category description of current post

Tags: wordpress, post, widget, categories

I'm using this plugin which displays the active category or subcategory description in a widget.

http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/category-description-widget

This works great when clicking a category or subcategory either directly from the menu or another widget.

However, i also wanted to show this widget when viewing current post as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eg. let's say our category and sub-categories are structured accordingly:

- Geography
  ---- Ocean
  ---- Land

**This is how it currently works:**

When i click on Geography, all posts under Geography is displayed.
In the widget, the plugin displays the description for Geography.

When i click on ocean, all posts under Ocean is displayed.
In the widget, the plugin displays the description for Ocean.

**I would like to add additional:**

When I'm in a post under Ocean, the widget should display the description of Ocean.

**Below is the plugin code:**

```
class Category_Description_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'category_description_widget', // Base ID
            'Category Description Widget', // Name
            array( 'description' => 'A widget with the category description', ) // Args
        );
    }
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if(!is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag()){
            return false;
        }
        extract( $args );
        echo $before_widget;
        echo term_description();
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

function category_description_widget_init(){
    register_widget('Category_Description_Widget');
}


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'category_description_widget_init');
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it.

```
class Category_Description_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'category_description_widget', // Base ID
            'Category Description Widget', // Name
            array( 'description' => 'A widget with the category description', ) // Args
        );
    }
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        global $post;

        if(!is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() && !is_single()){
            return false;
        }

        extract( $args );

        if ( is_single() ) {
            //Get current post category.
            $cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
            echo $before_widget;
            echo $cat[0]->category_description;
            echo $after_widget;

        } else {
            echo $before_widget;
            echo term_description();
            echo $after_widget;
        }
    }
}

function category_description_widget_init(){
    register_widget('Category_Description_Widget');
}


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'category_description_widget_init');
```